# How to handle large # of items in recycler view? (e.g. 1000s of comments)

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, android-recyclerview

I know how recycler views work. But I have always wondered how popular apps like Instagram - where posts can get upwards of 1000s to 100,000s comments.

[image]

It begs the question, how are they loaded into memory? Does the app just keep making HTTP requests to the server and appending it into an every growing `ArrayList` until it runs out of memory and suddenly just crashes?

Am I expected to believe that these apps are just moving around an `ArrayList` of length `12,000` into and out of `Bundle` objects?

Comment: To everyone down-voting legitimate questions, why do you have to be such cunts to beginner programmers? Have you never needed to ask rather plain questions when you were learning as well? Or are you just an asshole by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments require little space. Usually you just keep appending data to an internal model. Either the system will stop being able to add comments because of a lack of memory (at which point the application will likely crash), or in case of a low memory warning, a system can decide to unload the comments not currently visible from memory, and reload them via HTTP when they become visible again.